# Restrictions for Integer Programming problem with Simplex Method

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, integers, integer-programming, simplex

I have an integer programming problem:

max $F = −4x_1 + 3x_2$

subject to:

- $−x_1 + 3x_2 ≤ 9$
- $7x_1 − 3x_2 ≥ −7$
- $x_1 ≤ 3, x_2 ≥ 0$, and integer valued

How can I model the restriction that $x_1 > 2$ and $x_2 > 3$ cannot both hold at the same time?? I'm told to give explicit numerical values for any “Big M” that I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce binary variables $y_1$ and $y_2$ and impose linear big-M constraints:
\begin{align}
x_1 - 2 &\le M_1 y_1 \tag1 \\
x_2 - 3 &\le M_2 y_2 \tag2 \\
y_1 + y_2 &\le 1 \tag3 \\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $x_1 > 2 \implies y_1 = 1$.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces $x_2 > 3 \implies y_2 = 1$.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $\neg (y_1 \land y_2)$.

You want $M_1$ to be an upper bound on $x_1 - 2$ when $y_1=1$, so take $M_1 = 3 - 2 = 1$.  To determine a good value for $M_2$, first use the original constraints to deduce an upper bound on $x_2$.

Comment: Hello, is it possible to include an explanation on how to find the upper bound M1 and M2 ?

Comment: @RobPratt how would we find the bound $M_2$ in this case?

Comment: By your first constraint and the upper bound on $x_1$, we can deduce that $3x_2\le 9+x_1\le 9+3=12$, so $x_2\le 4$. Now you want $M_2$ to be an upper bound on $x_2-3$, so take $M_2=4-3=1$.